# Find Min time and Maxtime from one table and set the value in other table based on ID in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a Table named "process". Its structure is like below:

```
ID     Name               Date          Time
---    -------            --------      -------
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     9:30
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     9:31 
2      rajon              10/1/2014     9:15
2      rajon              10/1/2014     9:17
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     13:20 
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     13:29
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     14:10
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     15:40 
2      rajon              10/1/2014     11:15
2      rajon              10/1/2014     15:17
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     9:30
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     9:31 
2      rajon              11/1/2014     9:15
2      rajon              11/1/2014     9:17
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     13:20 
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     13:29
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     14:10
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     15:40 
2      rajon              11/1/2014     11:15
2      rajon              11/1/2014     15:17
```

I want to find out the value in another table like below:

```
ID     Name               Date          inTime        outtime
---    -------            --------      -------       -------
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     9:30          9:31
2      rajon              10/1/2014     9:15          9:17
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     13:20         13:29
1      shuvo              10/1/2014     14:10         15:40
2      rajon              10/1/2014     11:15         15:17
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     9:30          9:31
2      rajon              11/1/2014     9:15          9:17
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     13:20         13:29
1      shuvo              11/1/2014     14:10         15:40
2      rajon              11/1/2014     11:15         15:17
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to update the other table? Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to Insert the values in other table.

Comment: Do you have a column with a unique value?

Comment: what database engine do you use?

Comment: I took a leap of faith and picked MySQL for him :)

Answer (score 0):

This was really tricky...especially without any auto_incremented unique ID. Here is what I can come up with. I'm not experienced with stored procedures so forgive any flaws. This will only work if the whole table follow exactly the structure you shared.

First, start with inserting all the rows with only the inTime for the new table (and please use an auto_incremented column for this table). This should be every other row starting with the first one.

```
INSERT INTO other_table (ID, Name, Date, inTime) SELECT ID, Name, Date, Time 
FROM (SELECT@row := @row +1 AS rownum, ID, Name, Date, Time FROM 
(SELECT @row :=0) r, process) r2 WHERE rownum % 2
```

When you have all the new rows you need in other_table (just OutTime missing), you can use the following stored procedure to update the missing values row by row. They should exist on every second row as well in the old table.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update_other` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_other` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE row_counter INT;
    DECLARE what_limit INT;
    DECLARE stop_row INT;
    SET row_counter = 1;
    SET what_limit = 1;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM other_table INTO stop_row;

    WHILE row_counter <= stop_row DO
       UPDATE other_table SET Outtime = (SELECT Time FROM process LIMIT what_limit,1) WHERE unique_id = row_counter; 
       SET what_limit = what_limit + 2;
       SET row_counter = row_counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```